# Adjusting column width in siuntix table

Tags: tables, siunitx, columns

I have a table that I am trying to adjust the column width of, to make it a bit smaller. I am using `\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{.00001pt}`to do this. However, one column does not seem to respond to this adjustment.

Here's the table:

```
\documentclass[11pt. oneside]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{landscape}  
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}            
\usepackage{array}                              
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false 
]{caption}



\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false
]{caption}


\newcommand{\boldentry}[2]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{S[table-format=#1,
                   mode=text,
                    text-rm=\fontseries{b}\selectfont
                   ]}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} %Removes page number
\begin{table}[h]

\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{.00001pt}
 \begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{} %Adjusts table to the left, so all can be seen
\caption{This is the caption}
\begin{tabular}{lSSSSSSSSSSl} \toprule
{Header 1} & {\shortstack{Header (\textit{2})}} & {\shortstack{Header\\number 3}} & {\shortstack{Header\\ number 4}} &{ \shortstack{Header\\ 5}} & {\shortstack{Header\\number 6}} & {\shortstack{Header\\number 7}} & {Header number (8)}   & {\shortstack{Header\\number (9)}} & {Header number 10} & {Header number 11} & {\shortstack{Header \textit{Number 12}}} \\
\midrule
{TLR1234}       & {Total (10)}  & {100 mm}  & 100   & 200   & 300   & 400   & 500       & 600 {(700)}   &               &               &                 \\
& {ST (10)}         &               & 100           & 200           & 300           & 400       & 500       & 600   & 700           & 800   & 900 \\
& {FG (10)}         &               & 100       & 200           & 300        & 400      & 500       & 600       & 700           & 800   & {900 (1000)} \\
& {SN (10)}             &           & 100           & 200        & 300            & 400     & 500       & 600       & 700           & 800       & 900                \\
 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have found that it is the entry `600 {(700)}` that is causing the problem. If I remove the `{}`, the column follows the width adjustment, but it causes a problem of no space in between 600 and (700). If I do `{600 (700)}`, the column is still adjusted for width, but then the entry is not center aligned.
Can you give me a solution for this problem? The other entry also containing parenthesis `{900 (1000)}` in the table does not seem to cause a problem.

----EDIT----

With the solution provided by Zarko, I still have a few problems.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{landscape,letterpaper}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{table-number-alignment=center,
         table-format=3.0}

    \begin{document}
        \thispagestyle{empty} %Removes page number
    \begin{table}[h]
    %    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{.00001pt}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5cm}{} %Adjusts table to the left, so all can be seen
        \caption{This is the caption}
        \begin{tabular}{lcc*{9}{S}} 
            \toprule
    \thead{Header\\ 1} 
        &   \thead{Header\\ 2}
        &   {\thead{Header\\number 3}} 
            &   {\thead{Header\\ number 4}} 
                &   {\thead{Header\\ 5}} 
                    &   {\thead{Header\\number 6}} 
                        &   {\thead{Header\\ number 7}} 
                            &   {\thead{Header\\ number (8)}}   
                                &   {\thead{Header\\number (9)}} 
                                    &   {\thead{Header\\ number 10}} 
                                        &   {\thead{Header\\ number 11}}
                                            &   {\thead{Header\\ Number 12}}    \\
    \midrule
    TLR1234 & Total (10) & {100 mm} & 100 & 200 & 300 & 400 & 500 
      & {600 (700)} %<--- 
        &&&     \\
        & ST (10)        &          & 100 & 200 & 300 & 400 & 500 & 600 & 700 & 800 & 900 \\
        & {FG (10)}         &               & 100       & 200           & 300        & 400      & 500       & 600       & 700           & 800   
   & {900 (1000)} % <--- (this row  was not considered in my answer) \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
     \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{table}
        \end{document}
```

This gives me this result:

[image]

As in my original question, I still have the problem with no space between a value and the value in parenthesis. Further, I now have the problem with the entry in column 12 now extending further than the table.

**Edit:**
Since you used part of my answer I took liberty to correct it to be in agreement with its last version from my (now deleted) answer. In its second edit was described how to solve centering problem in cells, which contains two numbers, i.e. (with corrected spelling errors):

> In cell, which contain 600 (700) probably would be better to enclose
>   in curly braces like {600 (700)} and with this exclude from S
>   formatting:
>
> ```
> TLR1234 & Total (10) & {100 mm} & 100 & 200 & 300 & 400 & 500 &
>     {600 (700)}
>     &&&     \\
> ```

Since the intention of (each answer here) is show how to do (and not do-this-for-me) I expected, that you will use this solution in all other cells which I didn't take into consideration since the problem is the same.

All my corrections are indicated by `% <---`. With my answer I obtain the following result:

[image]

So, the real question for me is: which part of your original question was not fulfilled with my answer?

Comment: Are you really wanting to use a document font size of `19` pt?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Sorry, I changed it as part of an experiment. I have now changed it to 11 pt. It does not influence the problem, I think?

Comment: I expect that you will not use any solution from my deleted answer in any circumstance, since it was not satisfactory for you (regardless that it has solved all problems you expose in your edit) :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help, Zarko. I do not follow, how your solution solved the problems I mention in the edit, as the result (and the problems) of your exact solution are directly shown in the edit? The edit is a direct copy of your solution (except for the addition of one more row in the table, as you did not include this row from my original question). It may be that I am wrong, and your solution is perfect, but it would be much more helpful for a newbie as me (and for all other newbies), if you pointed out where I am wrong, instead of deleting your answer (+ the comments by me and others).